# Selenium IDE - selectWindow by title

Tags: selenium

I'm working with Selenium IDE.

I got a window W2 opened using a button in my webpage, with the command :

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

`url`is something like `http://example.com...`

My window is opened but goes back to my main window. I have to close W2 so I tried :

```
waitForPopUp(title=Sigma+ : Authentification Sigma+)
selectWindow(title=Sigma+ : Authentification Sigma+)
close()
```

I got the error `[error] Could not find window with title Sigma+ : Authentification Sigma+`, but my window W2 has this title :

```
<head>
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<title>Sigma+ : Authentification Sigma+</title>
....
```

I can't figure out why this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which language you are using,
but using c# you can handle this scenario using following code.

**Try following code. *C#***

```
 var allWindows = driver.WindowHandles;
            //for sencode window
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(allWindows.Last());
            //close sencode window using following
            driver.Close(); //it will close second window.
            //switch to main window.
            driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            //or 
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(allWindows.First());
            //to close firsrt window
            driver.Close();//it will close first window;
```

if any issue then let me know.